# Duplicity, amazon s3 backend exception

Tags: amazon-s3, backup, duplicity

I'm trying to create an auto backup using duplicity into amazon s3 following this guide: [easy server backups to amazon s3 with duplicity](http://icelab.com.au/articles/easy-server-backups-to-amazon-s3-with-duplicity/)

However, at this command:

```
duplicity /var/www s3+http://com.mycorp.myhost.backup
```

I encounter the error:

```
BackendException: Could not initialize backend: No module named boot
```

Googling does not yield understandable results for me. FYI, the actual command I run is:

```
duplicity /Users/okyretina/Dropbox/archive/ s3+http://com.sinkdrive.okyretina.dropbox.archieve
```

I understand that this guide is for linux and I am using mac osx lion but I figured it should work as well. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that I need to install boto first from [here](https://github.com/boto/boto)

Comment: I'm on OS X 10.8 and I ran `sudo easy_install boto`. Fixed it for me.

Answer (score 19):

If you are on debian/ubuntu you can install it via: sudo apt-get install python-boto

Comment: Warning: This may randomly break again during an upgrade. Also, if the above doesn't work, try `sudo pip install boto` instead.

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same problem *again* when upgrading to Ubuntu 19.10 and installing `python-boto` was not helping. Turns out `python3-boto` is required in newer versions.

```
sudo apt install python3-boto
```